# Notification window at certain time with traffic jams from work to home

Tags: macos, google-chrome, notifications, google-maps

Wow, today I saw a great window.

This is a notifier from google maps or apple maps that shows me a way to home from work at certain time (when I usually go home) with traffic jam.

Does anybody know what is it and which app / service show me that window?

I suppose that it can be a google chrome plugin or apple os x service. Not sure

Comment: Do you have the Google maps running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the Google Now feature.  If you have chrome installed and running, you can click the alarm-bell-like icon in your menu bar to configure it.

From [Google's support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/4414004?hl=en):

> ## How Google Now works in Chrome
>
> If you use Google Now **on your mobile device**, you can see certain Now
> cards on your desktop computer if you're signed into Chrome, including
> weather, sports scores, commute traffic, and event reminders cards.
> Some of **these cards may be based on the location of your mobile
> device**. [Learn how to sign into Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/185277)
>
> To see these cards, open the Chrome Notifications Center by clicking
> the bell icon  in the system tray on the lower right corner of your
> computer screen (on Windows) or in the menu bar on the upper right of
> your computer screen (on Mac).

Emphasis added.

Below is a screen shot showing where the bell is on my menubar (YMMV).

[image: Screenshot showing bell and its position in my menu bar]

Comment: sorry, can't see this item, can you add screenshot? (alarm-bell-like-icon)

Comment: Added screenshot, links, and more info

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that it was Apple maps? I see that the Apple Maps application in Yosemite *does* appear in the Notifications center configuration screen (in System Preferences). You can configure it to show as a banner or an alert.